Setting up a web worker using comlink
I have a worker file with the following code
import * as Comlink from "https://unpkg.com/comlink/dist/esm/comlink.mjs";

const renderPDFInWorker = async (props) => {
  try {
    const { renderPDF } = await import("../renderPDF");
    return URL.createObjectURL(await renderPDF(props));
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    throw error;
  }
};

Comlink.expose({ renderPDFInWorker: renderPDFInWorker });

And custom hook to use said hook
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useAsync } from "react-use";
import { wrap } from "comlink";

const useRenderPDF = ({ text }) => {
  const [url, setUrl] = useState(null); // Initialize error as null
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null); // Initialize error as null

  useEffect(() => {
    const worker = new Worker("./worker/worker.js");
    const PDFWorker = wrap(worker);
    const fetchData = async () => {
      setLoading(true);
      try {
        const newUrl = await PDFWorker.renderPDFInWorker({ text });
        setUrl(newUrl);
        setLoading(false);
      } catch (e) {
        setError(e.message);
        setLoading(false);
      }
    };

    fetchData();

    return () => {
      // Cleanup function to terminate the worker
      worker.terminate();
    };
  }, [text]);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Cleanup previous URL when URL changes
    return () => {
      if (url) {
        URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
      }
    };
  }, [url]);

  return {
    url,
    loading,
    error,
  };
};

export default useRenderPDF;


Now the problem is that when i do this i get this error:
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
Now reading i saw that you should move the worker to public folder. I did it but then i get error as i can't use import outside modules.
So i went to the html file and added this
But even so I still get the import error
Does anyone understanbd what is happening here? Or how to fix it?

Which bundler are you using? in Vite for example you could use https://vite.dev/guide/features.html#web-workers
const worker = new Worker(new URL('./worker.js', import.meta.url))

or
import MyWorker from './worker?worker&inline'

to create an inline worker.
With esbuild you can try this plugin

https://www.npmjs.com/package/esbuild-plugin-inline-worker

with Webpack is almost the same as Vite

https://webpack.js.org/guides/web-workers/

